# PowerBI connecting with Oracle-DB: ORA-12154

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, ora-12154

I am trying to connect **PowerBI** with **Oracle-DB** with no success.

- First: when I open **PowerBI** and try to connect the **Oracle Database** on **Get Data** Icon, I get the following error:

[image]

- Second: I click ok and try to set the connection mannualy:

[image]

But in the end I get the **ORA-12145: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified** error:

[image]

I don't know what's happening since my Oracle version is the most recent one (**Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production**):

[image]

Also, my PowerBI Desktop version is **Version: 2.63.3272.40262 64-bit (October 2018)**

I've already set up the **tsnames.ora** and **listener.ora** files, but nothing helped.

Do you have an idea how to figure that out?

Comment: Can you `tnsping` the database? Can you connect using SQLPlus?

Comment: Yes. the `tnsping` works to connect, but I don't know why **PowerBI** does not connect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that I was putting the server name wrong, for example I was just putting my db name like
Server : DB

and the way I fixed was
Server: Server/DB

Answer (score 0):

"Power BI" covers a lot of different components.  I presume/guess you mean Power BI Desktop?

Your Oracle Database version is not that relevant.  The important piece you are probably missing is the drivers, in this case the Oracle Data Access Client (ODAC) drivers.  Here's the  page in the manual you should read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database